# Visio 2010 - How to apply a template?

Tags: microsoft-visio, microsoft-visio-2010

I created a template (background and some stuff, a stencil too). What i want is

When I create a new diagram I want it to open with this template and I want my stencil to be in the shapes list.

How to that? I simply cannot find anything about this.

When I open the .vst file, I get the template with the stencil. But when I create a new drawing, how can that template file automatically be applied to it?

Answer (score 1):

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff468688.aspx

If Visio finds a stencil that has this exact file name (which must be the same file name in all languages) in the My Shapes folder, it will use it to populate the gallery, instead of the stencil that was included with Visio 2010. hope this helps